# A statistic minizing *Mean Absolute Relative Error*

Tags: statistics, median, mean-square-error

*Mean* of values (x1, ... xi,...xn) will minimize *Mean Square Error*, *Median* of values will minimize *Mean Absolute Error*.

I would intuite *Median* would also minimize *Mean Absolute Relative Error* (MARE) where:

$MARE(x)=\sum|\frac{x-x_i}{x_i}|$

... but at the end of the day I'm not able to prove it, and I didn't find any demonstration on this topic.

Many thanks for your help.

---

Following @Dap's answer I've drawn a short experiment to visually figure out the problem. This illustrates the weighted median minimizes the *Mean Absolute Relative Error* and the difference between the 3 metrics (MAE, MSE and MARE).

[Minization of MAE, MSE, MARE for 12 points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu5Fl.png)

Comment: Did you mean Mean Relative Absolute Error (MRAE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of the (discrete) [weighted medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_median) with weights $1/x_i,$ which are a special case of the medians of a measure.

They're not the same as the usual medians. For example $1,1000,1001$ has unique median $1000$ but the MARE is minimized by $1.$